# JSONArray with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSONArray Containing JSONObjects

```
[ { 'title': abc,  'details':xyz,}, {'title': abc2,'details':xyz2}]
```

How to parse it using jquery?

Comment: In what manner do you want to parse it? What is your desired output?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking, do you have the JSON as a string or is it already and array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parseJSON will convert your Json string into a javascript object. The code is something like

```
var array = $.parseJSON(json);
```

Then to access the variables you use code like

```
var title1 = array[0].title;  //title1 is abc
```

Comment: is this function available with jquery1.4.3-min  ?? i m not getting parseJSON in ide

Comment: Version added 1.4.1 so it should be available.

Comment: My json data contains HTML text.. & a URL too..  does it throw exception when  using parseJSON?

Comment: Once your string is encoded properly i.e. in double quotes it shouldn't throw an execption

Comment: ohk.. i guess the issue is with HTML it contains string like: <img src="">  is there a solution for avoiding exceptions.. it finads end at double quotation of HTML data in JSON

Comment: Put \\ in front of your quotes e.g. <img src=\\"myimg\\" etc. and it should work

Comment: Do you have access to the file that serves the request? If so what language is it in?

Comment: and does it have any purpose other than serving that request?

Comment: i am using java to access the feeds.. i am trying to replace the quotes using  `detail.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");` but, still it shows the the string as it is..

Comment: You need to escape each literal backslash (i.e. add another two backslashes). See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use parseJSON if your array is a string.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/